# What are the major issues with migrating wiki pages from SharePoint 2013 to 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration, wiki-pages

I am looking at creating a wiki in SharePoint 2013 for a knowledge base. If I go the wiki route what are the issues when it comes time to migrate to 2016 that I will have to deal with? From what I understand the migration from 2013 to 2016 will be much better than 2010 to 2013 but I am sure that is what they were saying the last time migration was being considered.

Answer (score -1):

If you have smaller number of pages, you could use backup / restore scripts. However, there are some limitations as some of the web parts (such as Report viewer web parts) used in SharePoint 2013 may be enhanced in SharePoint 2016.

So, moving of wiki pages from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 is not necessarily easy and the volume of pages could add to the complexity. You can take a look at a third party SharePoint migration tools such as Vyapin's [XPlica for SharePoint](http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-to-sharepoint/xplica/sharepoint-migration-tools-and-software), which is capable of handling wiki page migration across SharePoint versions.